# Xamarin UI Test iOS Simulator Connection refused

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, httprequest, xamarin-test-cloud

I am trying to use Xamarin.UITest locally, but I am getting a httprequest exception, saying that the connection has been refused
I am using xcode 9.3, vs 7.4.2 and an iphone 10.3 iphone x sim
Xamarin.Ui.Test 2.2.4, Xamarin.Testcloud.Agent 0.21.4, NUnit 3.10.1
When Trying to run my test I get the following Exception:

Xamarin.UITest.XDB.Exceptions.DeviceAgentException : DeviceAgent start session failed: An error occurred while sending the request
 ----> System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException : An error occurred while sending the request
 ----> System.Net.WebException : Error: ConnectFailure (Connection refused)
 ----> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException : Connection refused

Comment: Could you try resetting the SIM to make sure it's not got in to a strange state?

Comment: Whilst I believe UITest isn't supported on NUnit 3 - I don't think that'll be the cause of your error when running locally. Is it possible to add the whole output of the test run as part of your question? Then I can see how far it gets in the process.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got it working by restarting the mac and putting the Calabash.Start() call right on top of the FinishedLaunching method. If one or both saved the day, I don't know.

Comment: My gut says restarting the Mac. Glad you got it sorted!

Answer (score 0):

Although it's an old post, others might look for it.
That error means that the simulator doesn't start quickly enough for the next test.

There is an active bug opened here https://github.com/Microsoft/appcenter/issues/340#

What you can do is either set the variable to 0 and manually restart the emulator to pick the new code.

Also, be sure that NUnit package version is max 2.6.x. Newest 3.0 is not supported by Xamarin.UITest